# Hidden toggled div is interfering with non-toggled links

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page has toggled content that is preventing the other page content from being selectable or clickable. Is there a way to keep my general page layout the same, but still give users the ability to select the text and links within the "page-content" div?

I can add a positive z-index value to that "page-content" div, which would appear to solve the problem, but of course that covers up the toggled content, defeating the purpose.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toggleDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

.page-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
}

.toggle-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.button-1 {
  background-color: beige;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#toggleDiv {
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.link-box {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 75%;
  height: 225px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 12.5%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: beige;
}

.link-box a {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 7%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-content">
    <p>The hidden toggled div is preventing you from selecting the text or clicking the link.</p>

    <p>Praesent sit amet turpis fringilla urna maximus pharetra quis faucibus est. Nunc ligula turpis, interdum at libero sed, auctor gravida justo. Phasellus odio dolor, pulvinar pellentesque egestas in, scelerisque ac orci. Orci varius natoque penatibus
      et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque tempor, ipsum et porttitor fringilla, neque risus lacinia purus, et congue purus erat non nisi. Pellentesque urna neque, varius egestas risus sit amet, mollis iaculis lacus. Sed
      sit amet quam a tortor malesuada pharetra quis ac mi. In a risus feugiat, consectetur lacus ut, posuere elit. Etiam a magna vehicula, volutpat quam quis, interdum tellus. Sed dictum vulputate consequat.</p>
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
  </div>
  <!--page-content-->

  <div class="toggle-wrapper">
    <button class="button-1" onclick="myFunction()">toggle</button>
    <div id="toggleDIV" style="display: none;">
      <div class="link-box">
        <p>Toggle Content </p>
        <a href="#">
          <p>Link 1</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <p>Link 2</p>
        </a>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <!--link-box-->
    </div>
    <!--#toggleDiv-->
  </div>
  <!--toggle-wrapper-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```

Comment: Your <a href="#">LINK</a> doesn't call your myFunction() method so you need to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd change the display of your popup a bit by removing the parent's block display, and setting the position of the inner link div to an absolute position so that it's removed from the flow of the document and doesn't block the elements behind it. Like this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toggleDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 350px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.page-content {
  position: absolute;
  width: inherit;
}

.button-1 {
  background-color: beige;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

#toggleDiv {
  width: 600px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.link-box {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 75%;
  height: 225px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: beige;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.link-box a {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 7%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="button-1" onclick="myFunction()">toggle</button>

  <div class="page-content">
    <p>The hidden toggled div is preventing you from selecting the text or clicking the link.</p>

    <p>Praesent sit amet turpis fringilla urna maximus pharetra quis faucibus est. Nunc ligula turpis, interdum at libero sed, auctor gravida justo. Phasellus odio dolor, pulvinar pellentesque egestas in, scelerisque ac orci. Orci varius natoque penatibus
      et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque tempor, ipsum et porttitor fringilla, neque risus lacinia purus, et congue purus erat non nisi. Pellentesque urna neque, varius egestas risus sit amet, mollis iaculis lacus. Sed
      sit amet quam a tortor malesuada pharetra quis ac mi. In a risus feugiat, consectetur lacus ut, posuere elit. Etiam a magna vehicula, volutpat quam quis, interdum tellus. Sed dictum vulputate consequat.</p>
    <a href="#">LINK</a>
  </div>
  <!--page-content-->

  <div class="toggle-wrapper">
    <div id="toggleDIV" style="display: none;">
      <div class="link-box">
        <p>Toggle Content </p>
        <a href="#">
          <p>Link 1</p>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <p>Link 2</p>
        </a>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      <!--link-box-->
    </div>
    <!--#toggleDiv-->
  </div>
  <!--toggle-wrapper-->
</div>
<!--container-->
```